# How to effectively change authentication method in ASP. NET web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to launch ASP.NET project on a local computer. IIS responds with 401.0 status code, stating that "authenticated user does not have access to a resource needed to process the request". Authentication mode is set to Windows in my web config, nonetheless logon method in Detailed Error Information is "Anonymous". Changing it to "None" brought no change. So how do I change authentication method that way so I log in via Windows Authentication?

Comment: Why is the application using Windows Authentication in the first place? Is it using Win32 / Kerberos security impersonation, SSPI, token exchange, etc?

Comment: I don't even know, this is legacy and original author does not work here anymore. Impersonation setting was commented out, but existed, I've uncommented it but nothing changed. Maybe Windows Authentification is used because this is web app for internal use in company.

Comment: Do you have the full edition of IIS installed? (_not_ IIS Express)? Along with all of the optional componnets and the management tools?

Comment: Partially, I guess, not everything is ticked in the Windows Features and I can't tick more, because I don't have admin rights on this PC.

Comment: "I don't have admin rights on this PC" - uhhh, what? I'm pretty sure that's _legally defensible grounds_ for quitting your job and burning your office down to cinders....

Comment: Guess we have different jobs then :). Moreover, this app was written within same information security restrictions without local admin rights, so it is possible somehow. It's not that we can't change something on our PCs, we just have to file a request and it will be done.

Comment: Yeah, I feel you're kinda SOL for now. I guess you're in an AD Domain Environment then? So I _was_ going to suggest firing-up a VM where you would have local-admin access, but it sounds like it's using NTLM/Kerberos for delegated/impersonated security for other network resources (SQL Server? Network Shares? Local disk NTFS ACLs?) in which case that wouldn't work.

Comment: Still, you could still fire-up a VM to install IIS and get to play around with it in the meantime until your org's [IT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzMCjcVzPcM) folks unblock you (I might suggest _senna_ in that case...)

Comment: So it can be due to failure of DB connection? I had such a guess, but didn't give it a go. Should I play around with different ways to connect/log in to DB? Also, if it helps you, the same app is live on servers now, so it accesses DB with the same credentials, that are written into this project.

Comment: Where are the connection-strings stored and what do they look like? Is it MS SQL Server? Do they have `Trusted Connection=SSPI` or `Integrated Security` in them instead of a `UserId`/`Password`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243469/discussion-between-ventisk1ze-and-dai).

Answer (score 0):

I found out what happened and it’s hilarious. Turns out that Windows Auth was disabled in project properties, and anonymous auth was enabled instead. All the info I found before gave advice of opening project properties and switching auth method to Windows Auth. I tried to do this but somehow properties window didn't open, and they said that it was to open right on click on the project in solution explorer.
And it actually did open, although my laptop's screen covered the area of monitor where it opened. So when I closed my laptop I immidiately saw needed properties panel, switched auth method, fired up IIS and everything got into order.
So here's my wisdom: always make sure that you see the whole picture :)